# how does rails implicitly import functions from gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby and rails. I see that any gems that I have included, I can directly use its functions in my code. I do not see any imports for the code, nor any name spaces for the functions. Isn't this recipe for conflicts, if the gems contain functions with same names ?

So -

How does ruby/rails imports the functions, how does it map a function to a gem ?
Can it lead to conflicts when 2 gems contain the same funcitons ?
If I want to explicitly use a ruby library, how will I import its code ?
Is there namespacing in ruby?

Answer (score 12):

### Ruby

The way ruby imports functions declared in one file into another file is via the `require` function. `load` accomplishes something similar, but for general purposes, `require` is usually what you want (see http://ionrails.com/2009/09/19/ruby_require-vs-load-vs-include-vs-extend/ for more details)

**hello_lib.rb**

```
def say_hello
  puts "hello"
end

# that's right, you can execute code when a library is required,
# so the sky's the limit of what you can do
puts "Hey, I've been required!"
```

**hello_caller.rb**

```
# load the code from `hello_lib.rb` in the same directory
require './hello_lib.rb'
```

**subdir/hello_other_caller.rb**

```
# for illustrative purposes, adding the parent directory to the load path
# so that ruby will look there for files I want to require
$: << '..'
require 'hello_lib.rb'
say_hello
```

### Gems

Gems can be thought of as a package of ruby code, or a library. There are a couple ways of loading a gem, but the most common is via `require` Say you've installed the `progressbar` gem for displaying simple progress bars in the terminal (`gem install progressbar`)

**progressbar_test.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'progressbar'

# this also works
# gem 'progressbar', '~> 0.9.2'

pbar = ProgressBar.new("test", 100)
100.times do
  sleep 0.1
  pbar.inc
end
pbar.finish
```

The reason this works, is that when we require `rubygems`, it's adding the progressbar gem to the path of where ruby looks for required files.

### Rails

Rails is just a collection of gems, some of which provide executable scripts. In previous versions, you had to specify the gems to load, much in the way we did above. But now, with `bundler`, we can specify all our gems in one `Gemfile`, along with versioning and source information. Bundler then will work out dependencies amongst the gems and keep our specific versioning for a project in `Gemfile.lock`. Since `bundler` itself is a gem, you'll often see code like this:

**config/application.rb**

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
```

This code tells Bundler to load all of the dependencies we listed flatly in our gemfile, as well as the ones we listed in the group corresponding to the current rails env (e.g. :development).

### Namespaces

Yes, you can run into issues in a couple ways. Two gems could have the same name, although they can't be pushed to rubygems in that case, and you'll discover that quickly. A more subtle namespace issue is if two files do something like this:

**hello1.rb**

```
def hello
  puts "Hi"
end
```

**hello2.rb**

```
def hello
  puts "Hello, there!"
end
```

**hello3.rb**

```
require './hello1'
require './hello2'
hello
```

Here we see what happens when we have a namespace conflict in the global namespace. Similar things can happen if two libraries define the same method in the same class name (and this type of monkey patching, while discouraged, still happens!). In practice, you don't run into this too much, especially when good discipline is used in terms of using Modules to namespace code, like if I'm writing a gem `hello`:

```
module Hello
  # not such a good name, but won't conflict with ::Object
  class Object
    def to_s
      puts 'this is a bad idea'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Gems are name-spaced so you can explicitly call a method by

```
ModuleName::Class
```

If you don't explicitly call an included Class, ruby will move through all its classes until it finds the one you have called, and if it doesn't, then it'll throw a NoMethod error.

For Ruby to see the library, you require it:

```
require 'some_library'
```

To include the library within a class, you:

```
class SomeClass
 include SomeLibrary
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in `config/application.rb`, you'll see how it does it:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

That's it! Bundler handles requiring all of the gems automatically so you don't have to in every file you use. For more details, see [the docs](https://bundler.io/v1.12/bundler_setup.html#setting-up-your-application-to-use-bundler).