# Ruby - Cannot use locally installed gem

Tags: ruby

I've written a simple PasswordGenerator gem that I have at `~/workspace/gems/password_generator` and have an app at `~/workspace/rubysamples/app` where I want to use it. I have a `Gemfile`, the content of it is this:

```
gem 'password_generator', path: '~/workspace/gems/password_generator'
```

I installed it locally, like this:

```
bundle install --local
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 1.16.5
Using password_generator 0.1.0 from source at `~/workspace/gems/password_generator`
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

It looks like it's installed locally:

```
bundle info password_generator
  * password_generator (0.1.0)
    Summary: Simple password generator
    Homepage: https://github.com/jedrekdomanski/password_generator
    Path: /home/jedrek/workspace/gems/password_generator
```

When I try to use it

#### ~/workspace/rubysamples/app/password_reset.rb

```
PasswordGenerator.generate
```

I get an error

```
uninitialized constant PasswordGenerator (NameError)
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing anything?

Here's my gem repo: https://github.com/jedrekdomanski/password_generator

I also tried pointing to my repo and branch in the Gemfile

```
gem 'password_generator', git: 'git@github.com:jedrekdomanski/password_generator.git', branch: 'master'
```

but I get the same error message `uninitialized constant PasswordGenerator (NameError)`

Comment: try to add `require 'password_generator'`

Comment: Well, I think I shouldn't have to but I already tried that and got an error `require': cannot load such file -- password_generator ~ (LoadError)`

Comment: is the file called `password_generator.rb`? We have no idea what your gem looks like so it is very difficult to help

Comment: maybe upload your sample app on github? it will be easier to help.

Comment: Seems using `path` in the Gemfile is causing this... when running ruby through bundle exec it works fine for me `bundle exec ruby test.rb`

Comment: @engineersmnky I added my gem repo in the description. It does have PasswordGenerator module.

Comment: when I run `bundle exec ruby password_reset.rb` I get an error `undefined method `generate' for PasswordGenerator:Module (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Please provide the way, how you use that gem. Inside of Rails app, or by calling some ```rake``` task, or from Rails console?

Comment: As I wrote in my original question, I have a file password_reset.rb where I do PasswordGenerator.generate. This module and its method do exist in this gem. So I am building a separate ruby app and in there I try to use it.

Comment: What's in password_reset.rb

Comment: I also wrote that in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are potentially two issues. The first is how you are starting Ruby and the second is how you are requiring your module.

First, if you are starting Ruby by running `ruby password_reset.rb` then you are ignoring the `Gemfile`. The `Gemfile` is only used when you're using `bundler`, so you want to make sure you are starting Ruby by running `bundle exec ruby password_reset.rb`. This causes bundler to read your Gemfile and execute Ruby in that context.

Second, you're not properly including your module in your Ruby file. Just because you've added the gem to your Gemfile and started Ruby using bundler doesn't mean that the Ruby process knows you intend to use that gem's module; it just makes the module *available* for use. You might wonder, "Why don't I have to do that in Rails?" Because [Rails does that for you automatically via `config/application.rb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763555/3784008).

Given these two issues, the correct way to accomplish your goal is to configure your app as follows:

First, create your `Gemfile`:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'password_generator', path: '~/workspace/gems/password_generator'
```

Second, create your `password_reset.rb` file:

```
# password_reset.rb
# Manually require any libraries that this app will use, even if defined in Gemfile
require 'password_generator'
# Call `puts` so something is printed to the console when this app runs
puts PasswordGenerator.generate
```

Third, run `bundle install` to ensure your `Gemfile` is properly formatted and to generate your `Gemfile.lock`:

```
⇒  bundle install
Using bundler 1.16.5
Using password_generator 0.1.0 from source at `../../gems/password_generator`
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Fourth, run `bundle exec ruby password_reset.rb` and observe the output:

```
⇒  bundle exec ruby password_reset.rb
kpiDfyTxtdAsKmYuZqmK
```

Everything works because:

1. Ruby is started with Bundler
2. Bundler reads your Gemfile and makes the gems available to Ruby
3. Your app requires the module from the gem before attempting to use the module